# cufon hover stays in hover state after mouse out.

Tags: css, hover, cufon

I believe this might be one of the most common problem that users faces when they uses hover in cufon. Furthermore, there might be tons of solutions, but I have tried to no avail. Please help me. the website that I am having trouble with is [[here]]

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('.menubar a').hover(function(){ 
       jQuery('menubar a').css('color','#000000'); 
       Cufon.refresh('menubar a'); 

    },function(){ // this is the mouse out 

       jQuery('menubar a').css('color','#707070'); 
       Cufon.refresh('menubar a'); 
   }); 
});
```

I have also tried several attempt of refreshing the cufon using Cufon.refresh(). The hover still doesnt work. is there another solution or am I missing out something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting *every* `.menubar a` instead of only the one that was hovered. Try `this`: <sup>(pun intended)</sup>

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('.menubar a').hover(function(){ 
       jQuery(this).css('color','#000000'); 
       Cufon.refresh(this); 
    },function(){ // this is the mouse out 
       jQuery(this).css('color','#707070'); 
       Cufon.refresh(this); 
   }); 
});
```

Not only that, several of your selectors are `menubar a` when they should be `.menubar a` <sup>(note the `.`)</sup>.

Comment: Omg, thanks madmartigan. I didn't notice my own mistake. =/ thanks a lot!